# Manipulate folder struct in a zip file ( linux && (bash || cgi script) ) without uncompressing

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zip, cgi

I want to write a `script` that manipulates many zip files. Same folder struct are in all archive files. I would like to change that.

I am reading for a while the `zip` manual and i can not figure out how to do the following.
I am wondering, are these tasks possible without unzipping the archive file?

1. Move files inside a zip archive from a folder1 to an other folder2.
2. Rename folders in a zip archive file.

Example:

The original struct in the zip file:

```
       +folder0
         + folder1
            +folder2
               - file1.xyz
               - file3.xyz
               ...
            +folder3
               - file4.xyz
               ...
          ...
```

I want to change this to:

```
        +newFolderName
            +folder2
               - file1.xyz
               - file3.xyz
               ...
            +folder3
               - file4.xyz
               ...
```

A possible way :

1. Move the subfolders of `folder1` to `folder0`
2. delete `folder1`
3. rename `folder0` to `newFolderName`

Why do i need to do this without uncompress the archive file:

- Not enough space on disk ( the compressed files are big )
- As i experienced in desktop mode, the renaming of a folder in zip file is mutch faster than uncompress->change the folder name->compress again. I need a script that runs as fast as it possible.
- The idea is failed, to create a ram disk and do the uncompressing there (not enough memory)
- An other idea: can i mount the zip file as a partition, and then manipulate like a `real` partition ?

I can install applications on the server, if `zip` application is not the best tool for this task.

Anyone have experiences with same task?

Thanks for advice.

EDIT:

As I read in @Nickolay Olshevsky 's answer this feature might not be implemented in `zip` and in other official linux command line tools/applications.
So I began to find a solution on a bit different way.

PHP can be used as CGI script, and I have PHP interpreter on the server so the solution (in PHP as CGI script) is: 
(Something like this can be written python/ruby/... script or c/c++ app with libzip, and many other programming/scripting languages )

```
#!/usr/bin/php5
<?php
      //requires PHP5.3+ 
      $path = $argc?$argv[1]:'./';   
      $dh = opendir($path);               
      $oldPath = 'folder0/folder1/';
      $newPath = 'newFolder/'
      $zip = new ZipArchive();
      $warning = false;
      while( $entry = readdir( $dh ) ){
          if( 'zip' == array_pop(explode('.',$entry)) && $zip->open($entry) ){
               $success = true;
               print "Processing zip archive $path$entry: \n";
               for( $i=0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++ ){  
                    $oldName = $zip->getNameIndex($i);                          
                    $newName = preg_replace("#^$oldPath#",
                                          $newpath,
                                          $oldName);
                    print "  Renaming $oldName to $newName ... "
                    if($zip->renameIndex($i,$newName)){
                        print "OK\n";
                    }else{
                        $warning = true;
                        $success = false;
                        print "FAILED\n";
                        break;
                    }
              }
              if( $zip->close() ){
                  print "$path$entry PROCESSED\n";
              }else{
                  print "Warning: Something went wrong with $path$entry !!!\n";
              }
          }
      }
      closedir($dh);
      return $warning?1:0;
?>
```

But back to my original question :

When somebody find a solution what uses only bash and official (debian) linux command line zip/gzip/... etc tools i accept that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an easy task due to ZIP archive structure. Paths there stored as variable-length fields, and when you will change the path of file, it will take more/less bytes and you'll need to move all the data after this file record. This is possible without recompression, but I doubt that somebody implemented such feature.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a little. I found a solution in php, and created a cgi script in php, that solved the problem. Not exactly what i wanted but works.